# How to read read a value from firebase document field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

here is the firebase firestore section

[image]

how do I read the value 'purchase-id'

this is how I did, but not working

```
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
          final docSnapshot = await collection.doc('$index').get();
          
          Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;
          final purID = data['purchased-id'];
```

the value is receiving but as the future value
here is how the value is receiving

`final purchaseID = coursePurchaseCheck`

but this is a Future value, how do I parse that to normal data

how do I properly get document value from firebase??

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: In your case `$index` does probably not match any document-id. Please read the documentation first. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Check your index is equal to document key ??

You can get document key with below code:

```
 List<String> _userKey = [];
 await fireStore
      .collection('user').get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      _userKey.add(doc.id);
    }
  });
```

And get data below:

```
for(String _key in _userKey){
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('user')
          .doc(_key)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          var data = documentSnapshot.data();
          var res = data as Map<String, dynamic>;
          final purID = res['purchased-id'];
        }
      });
   }
```